# Designing a opera seat picking layout

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm creating a layout which is going to contain over 200 seats. It need to be zoomable and dragable (already done). What cause me trouble is that some of the seat are tilted and I can't arrange them in a nice way so they will be aligned.
This is what I've mannaged to achieve:
[image: This is what I've mannaged to achive]
This is how I want it to be looking in the end :
[image]

The second problem witch I don't know how to solve is how do I know which seat is in which row and what is it's number. I will be needing this so I can properly book seat. Right now I'm assigning them ids but it doesn't looking like the best idea.

Right now I'm adding seats in xml witch is killing me. There are over 1000 seat in whole opera. Is there a way I can add them pragmatically (note in each row there is different number of seats.)?

```
 <ZoomableRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_floor_zoomablarelativelayout_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="54dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="49dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:rotation="20">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="2"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="3"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="4"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button5"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="5"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button6"
                    style="@style/Button_Seat_Not_Occupied"
                    android:background="@drawable/button_seat_picker"
                    android:text="6"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ZoomableRelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just be easier to have your seating plan as an SVG?

Comment: I haven't heard about SVG since now. I'm surely going to check this out more deeply. Would you rather place every seat in separate SVG or put them all in one SVG?

Comment: All in one SVG, giving each seat an ID so you can refer to them individually to set properties like the css class, to indicate occupied, free etc.